# PhpStorm xdebug how to open big cachegrind file

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have 3,5 GB file `cachegrind.out` file to check and  try to open it in PhpStorm. I have increased needed values of PhpStorm to open this huge file, but finally my IDE crashed.

Has xdebug some options which can decrease profiler file size?

Comment: Try other tools for opening such huge files: PhpStorm (and all JetBrains IDEs) is not that great with handling huge files (especially that huge).

Comment: I've also tried WInCacheGrind but this tools also crached on this file. I have there error > Cannot find call target

Answer (score 1):

when you use an xdebug older than version 2.3.0 you could update it to reduce the size of the generated file.
Xdebug 2.3.0 from 2015-02-22 added the compressed file format
[bugtracker: Support for filename and function name compression in cachegrind files](https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00001054)

Comment: I have a 2.4 version. How to enable compressed files format?

Comment: you don't need to enable it. it is always on.